# Rails: Namespace is Applied to Associations in Unintended Ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces, associations

I have a namespaced model `Collection::Publication` with a `has_many` relationship to another namespaced model `Library::Publication`. The association declaration looks like this:

```
has_many :library_publications, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Library::Publication"
```

Yet when I try something like this:

```
@collection_publication.library_publications
```

I get this error:

```
NameError at /
uninitialized constant Collection::Publication::Library::Publication
```

It seems that Rails is namespacing the associated model, even when I explicitly define the `class_name`. Am I understanding this correctly? And if so, what can I do to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a typo in the `Library::Publication` declaration:

```
class Libary::Publication
  ...
end
```

Although the error message declared that it wasn't finding `Collection::Publication::Library::Publication`, this must have been only the last place it looked. Once `Library::Publication` was properly defined, Rails found it without problem.